# Length of binary encoding in Huffman algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, huffman-code

What is the length of the longest binary encoding that occurs when using Huffman’s
algorithm with the weights 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 50?

Is there a fast way to do this or do i have to build the tree and then calculate the average number of bits which I guess would be:

= total length / number of bits

This is the tree I generated:

[image]

Comment: Well, yeah, there's a fast way. With only seven weights it should take you about a minute to draw the tree with a pencil and paper. Assuming you understand the Huffman coding algorithm.

Comment: @jim I created the tree. How do I proceed now?

Comment: Yes, you have to make the tree. You can find a lower bound from the entropy, which is the negative of the sum of the probabilities times the log (base 2) of the probabilities.

Comment: @Mark like this: (10*4 + 10*4 + 10*4 + 10*4 + 15*3 +15*3 + 50*1)/120 = 2.5 this is the avg# bits per character I guess?

Comment: or is the answer below correct?

Comment: No, the lower bound (entropy) is 2.47 bits. Yes, the answer is 4. You can just count the maximum number of branches to get to a leaf in the tree in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the longest binary encoding that occurs when using Huffman’s algorithm is equal to the height of the tree, which in this case is 4. So longest length would be 4.

It can be easily seen, that when you assign 0 to left branch and 1 to right branch( you can also do it vice versa), the codes would be:

```
50: 0

10: 1000

10: 1001

10: 1010

10: 1011

15: 110

15: 111
```